# Загрузить элемент в зависимости от размера окна

Tags: jquery

Как загрузить элемент на сайте,только тогда когда размер окна,например меньше 320px ?
Именно загрузить,а не отображать.

Comment: @Prodius, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Вешайте событие на $(window).resize(); внутри него получайте размер вьюпорта $('html').width(); ставьте условие, если размер < 321 то загружайте елемент $('.mydiv').load('/h/myurl.html'); и незабудте "триггернут" событие при инициализации, как то так: $(document).ready(function(){ $(window).trigger('resize'); });

- ну а вообще так не делают,  обычно display: none/block в зависимости от css media query более чем достаточно!